# Using hash table variable in Get-AdUser

Tags: powershell

Consider the following code fragment

```
$User = @{Username = "fred.bloggs"}
$Username = $User.Username
Get-AdUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $Username}               # this works
Get-AdUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $User.Username}          # this throws an error
```

The first Get-User works but the second fails with:

> Get-AdUser : Property: 'Username' not found in object of type: 'System.Collections.Hashtable'.

I'm aware of PowerShell's parsing quirks with objects and left-to-right parsing and would normally wrap this in $($User.Username) but that doesn't work either.

I know the answer is simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `-Filter` is looking for a `System.String`, you can get around the parsing issue by using double quotes instead of a script block:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($User.Username)'"
```

`Get-ADUser` will convert any script block passed to `-Filter` to a string for evaluation, so it can be helpful to use a string in the first place.

Comment: I'm going to have to go back and re-read the documentation on substitution. I did sit through the PluralSight training video which did a very good job. This works but I always thought that single quotes means "don't expand variables" but that's clearly not the case here as $x = "SamAccountName -eq '$($User.Username)'" ends up with $x containing "SamAccountName -eq 'fred.bloggs'"

Comment: I guess the "reason" here is as you say - I was passing a script block and not a string. Script block parsing may be different kettle of fish to string parsing

Comment: the variable here gets interpreted because the single quotes are part of the string and not interpreted like if used to surround the string.

Comment: Ahh thanks Paul - that's obvious now you point it out. The single-quote/double-quote differences only apply to the whole string

Comment: And in general, me using script blocks in the first place is a bad habit I've picked up somewhere as -Filter definitely needs a string. In the past, I've obviously been lucky that the ToString() function has worked

Comment: i wonder if -filter is converted to a scriptblock behind the scenes since the following syntax is given in the help:
<filter> ::= "{" <FilterComponentList> "}"

Comment: Script block notation for the `-Filter` parameter is the [advanced filter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2009/04/03/active-directory-powershell-advanced-filter.aspx) notation. This is converted to a string, which is then converted to an LDAP filter behind the scenes for evaluation on the server side.

Comment: Thanks Kohlbrr for the explanation and the link, i also probably found the reason why Robs code doesnt work :) 
Note: Advanced Filter does not support indexer (ex: $a[0]) and Function invocation (ex: $a.ToString()) inside filters.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly i cannot tell you why it fails but this could be a workaround for you:

```
$filter = [scriptblock]::create("SamAccountName -eq $($User.Username)")
Get-AdUser -filter $filter
```

If you find out the reason for the behaviour you experienced i would be happy to hear about it :)

Regards

Update:

The probable reason this happens is because `-Filter` expects a String, if given the expression inside of `{}` it will interpret it as Advanced Filter, which do not support function invocation and stuff like this.
Source: [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adpowershell/archive/2009/04/03/active-directory-powershell-advanced-filter.aspx) (Thanks Kohlbrr)